# Dealing with unreported failures in a survival analysis

Tags: survival

I'm doing a reliability analysis for some industrial equipment and am facing the problem that only a small proportion of the failures which occur in the field are actually reported (basically only those that are still covered by warranty at time of failure, which is small relative to the lifetime of the equipment).

This is causing my survival curves to be very inflated, but I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate tool within the survival analysis framework to deal with this. If I censor unobserved failures at the end of the warranty period, the survival curves become unrealistically long-tailed under the influence of the few observed failures. Truncation also doesn't seem to offer a solution.

Any advice on this?